# How can I run unit tests / code sniffs for individual modules using a CI provider?

Tags: magento2, module, testing, deployment, continuous-integration

At the company I work with, our modules are individual repositories. We add those as composer packages to our Magento 2 installation by adding GitHub as a repository in our `composer.json`:

```
"require": {
    "vendor/custom-module": "dev-master"
},
"repositories": [
    {
      "type": "git",
      "url": "git@github.com:CompanyName/custom-module.git"
    }
],
"autoload": {
    "files": [
        "registration.php"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "Happy\\PrivateProducts\\": ""
    }
},
```

This works fine, no questions there.

The next thing we want to do is set these modules up as individual testable modules using a Continuous Integration provider (CircleCI in our case). So I've added dependencies like `phpunit` and `phpcs` to the `composer.json` of our module:

```
"require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "5.3.5",
    "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "1.5.3"
}
```

We setup our `master`-branch to be protected and do our work in the `development`-branch. When we want to merge the changes we send a pull request to our `master`-branch. This is the moment where CircleCI kicks in.

Everything gets installed properly on our CI servers' container that is spawned. However, when I try to run `phpunit` or `phpcs` from the command line (using `vender/bin/phpunit` or `vendor/bin/phpcs` for example), I get a PHP error that all kind of Magento dependencies are missing:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar' not found in /home/ubuntu/custom-module/registration.php:6
Stack trace:
#0 /home/ubuntu/custom-module/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php(66): require()
#1 /home/ubuntu/custom-module/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php(56): composerRequiref6475a93b986d5b841accb13703f079a('bdaf00c9b7defe0...', '/home/ubuntu/ma...')
#2 /home/ubuntu/custom-module/vendor/autoload.php(7): ComposerAutoloaderInitf6475a93b986d5b841accb13703f079a::getLoader()
#3 /home/ubuntu/custom-module/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit(45): require('/home/ubuntu/ma...')
#4 {main}
```

thrown in /home/ubuntu/mage2-private-products/registration.php on line 6

### My question

I have a fairly good idea of why I'm getting this error. After all, I have the `registration.php` in my `composer.json` autoload-property. However, I am wondering what's best practice here?

- <del>Should I omit the `registration.php` from my `composer.json`-file?</del>
- Should I include the complete Magento framework as dev-dependency? (I don't think so because my unit tests should mock everything).
- Should I wrap my register function with a `if class_exists()`?
- Some other solution / suggestion?

What are other peoples experiences / best practices when it comes to individual module testing / CI processes with Magento 2?

**Edit:** I found out that if I omit my `registration.php` autoload in my `composer.json`, that Magento 2 will not see my module (which makes sense). For now I've included the Magento Framework (`magento/framework`) as a development dependency and added an `auth.json` for the credentials. I guess that's the best way to do this, but I'm still interested in other peoples' experiences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your composer.json your are autoloading `registration.php`, which requires `Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar`. So you have a dependency on the `magento/framework` package. If you add it to your composer.json you should be good to go.